# Have any English words been turned foreign only to be then used again in English in an altered state?

Tags: history, historical-change, loanwords, language-evolution, world-english

What are some examples of English words that got taken into use in a foreign language in a changed state, and then subsequently re-entered the English language in state B or even state C.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s more of a poll or request for items or ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @SConroy et al.: Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).